# Custom Membership Provider ASP.NET with custom database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, custom-membershipprovider

I have been struggling a few days with creating a simple user authentication to a webapp i am developing. I want a simple login function with logged-in-only pages.

I do already have a database with users which i need to use, and this is not a ASP.NET membership database.

I don't want to belive that this is a hard task to solve, but it sure seems like it.

Can someone please help me on the way?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Comment: Does that really solve my problem? Not sure how to implement it, feels like there´s alot missing. Is there any blogpost or such that still works? All blogposts i have found is 5-7 years old.

Comment: "All blogposts i have found is 5-7 years old" - Maybe that is because Membership is over 10 years old and has been superseded by [Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity)...

Comment: Why you want use `membership` instead of `ASP.NET Identity`?